# Rolling ScrollView for children position within LinearLayout (Solution)

Tags: android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

This post is not actually a question, but a solution for someone who is experiencing or may experience the problem I found.

I have an Activity that use one ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tb_pergunta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_principal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_table"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Within the `LinearLayout` the `ScrollView` I attribute "n" Layouts created dynamically. So with that, I have a layout set to put in the `ScrollView`.

These dynamic layouts also receive children of various types of `widgets` (`RadioButton`, `CheckBox`, `EditText`, `TextView`, `etc`).

How are dynamically created, they do not have a certain position within the parent `LinearLayout`. With that, I had a hard time rolling the `ScrollView` to these children.

Get the position of Layouts parents was easy, it was only taking the childAt get (index) of the main `LinearLayout` (which is within the `ScrollView`).

```
parentPosition = lnMain.getTop();
```

But to scroll to the position of children, I suffered.

End. The way I found to scroll to the children was to get the position of the top "lnParent.getTop ()" and the position of the top of the children who are in it.

```
childPosition = lnChild.getTop();
```

Added the father's position with the child's position:

```
scrollPosition = parentPosition + childPosition;
```

And I got her son's position within the `ScrollView` that would equal Layout Top position dad with Top position of the child.
After that, just go to the `ScrollView` the position of the child that was found in the above sum.

```
final int posicaoArray = arrayFilhoOpcao.get(contArray_z + 1);

myScrollLayout.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    myScrollLayout.smoothScrollTo(0, arrayPosition);
}
```

});

The `ArrayList` I created to put all the positions of the children layout that I'm currently browsing.

Well ... I hope you serve someone and that seem silly to others, many beginners like me sometimes finds it very difficult to get solutions to problems that would be simple for others.

I hope to serve Algue and also hope to have explained well, something I'm not very good. But no doubt, I am available. 
Hug!